# Grouping Hours by Week in using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to sum total hours worked and group them by week. My week starts Monday and ends Sunday.  The problem i am having is that the numbers are always of the first week but the rest of the weeks are fine. The problem with the first week always which is very low.

See the snapshot

[image]

Here is my code

```
SELECT
    UID, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, x.WeekBeginDate, 101) as WeekBeginDate, 
    x.TOTAL_HOURS 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         UID,  
         DATEADD(DD, CONVERT(INT, (DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7)) * 7, '1/1/1900') [WeekBeginDate],
         SUM(HOURS) AS TOTAL_HOURS 
     FROM 
         myTable t 
     WHERE 
         UID = 'test1' 
         AND DT >= DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GetDate()) 
     GROUP BY 
         UID, CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(DD, '1/1/1900', t.DT)/7) ) x 
ORDER BY  
    1
```

Comment: You can use DATEPART(wk) instead of dividing the day by 7.

Comment: Isn't that because your starting time is DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GetDate()), which is not a Monday, but whatever time it was 6 weeks ago, including hours and minutes

Comment: Instead of that super statement create a calendar table and calculate through joins. You will be surprized how things can be simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to simplify your query and get your window correct (fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35c8e/1):

```
set datefirst 1; --set first day of week to monday
select 
    DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt) - 1) * -1,dt) as WeekBeginDate,
    SUM(hours) AS TotalHours
from hours
where
    uid = 'test1'
    and dt >= CAST(DATEADD(WEEK,-6,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1) * -1,GETDATE())) AS date)
group by DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt) - 1) * -1,dt)
```